# Chebyshev first and second kind recurrence

Tags: polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

I have this quantity:

$ T_n(x) = \exp\big[i\cdot n\arccos(x)\big] $

How can i represent the polynomials of first and second kind?

I tried substituting $n = 0$ and $n = 1$ but i don't know when to stop and plot the generative function

**EDIT using MathLaTeX**

$ T_0(x) = e^{i0\arccos(x)} = e ^ 0 = 1 $

$ T_1(x) = e^{i1\arccos(x)} = 1 $

$ T_2(x) = 2x(1)-1 = 2x-1$

$ T_3(x) = 2x(T_2(x))-T_1(x) = 2x-1(2x-1)-1=4x^2-2x-1$

$ T_4(x) = 2x(T_3(x))-T_2(x) = 2x(4x^2-2x-1)-(2x-1) = 8x^3-4x^2-4x+1$

[image: t0, t1, Chebyshev]

Comment: Please, write down your calculations using mathjax!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $$\exp(i\theta)=e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$$
the definition turns to $$T_n(x)= e^{in\cos^{-1}(x)}=\cos(n\cos^{-1}(x))+i\sin(n\cos^{-1}(x))$$
Thus, for example:
$$T_1(x)=\cos(\cos^{-1}(x))+i\sin(\cos^{-1}(x))$$

---

Edit: Now we have $$T_{n+1}(x)=e^{i(n+1)\cos^{-1}(x)}=e^{in\cos^{-1}(x)+{i\cos^{-1}(x)}}\\
=e^{in\cos^{-1}(x)}e^{i\cos^{-1}(x)}\\=T_n(x)T_1(x)$$
can you continue?

---

Also we have
$$T_{n+1}(x)-T_{n-1}(x)=e^{i(n+1)\cos^{-1}(x)}-e^{i(n-1)\cos^{-1}(x)}\\=
e^{in\cos^{-1}(x)}(e^{i\cos^{-1}(x)}-e^{-i\cos^{-1}(x)})\\=
2iT_n(x) \sin(\cos^{-1}(x))$$
Now you can find the generating function easily.

Comment: so just this? i don't have to make the plot and the entire recurrence?

Comment: @Fabiosoft see the edit please

Comment: ()1() is the generative function?

Comment: @Fabiosoft see the edit again

Comment: ok, so probably the generating function is the fraction of (1-tx)/(1-2tx+t^2) or this is the most general formula?